# How to capture metrics Separately for GET,POST and PUT method for given REST Endpoint using spring boot actuators

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, metrics, spring-boot-actuator

**How to capture metrics Separately for GET,POST and PUT method for given REST Endpoint using spring boot actuators.**

Ex
by default we get :- "gauge.response.customer": 631,
i need

1. "gauge.response.customer.GET": 631,   OR "gauge.response.GET.customer": 631,
2. "gauge.response.customer.POST": 1631,   OR "gauge.response.POST.customer": 1631

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I do not believe you can break the endpoints down like that.  However, I do know that actuator is very flexible and you can add new metrics to that endpoint.  It looks like you are interested primarily in counters so I would recommend using the CounterService that Spring boot has.

```
private CounterService counterService;

@Autowired
public MyClassName(CounterService counterService) {
    this.counterService = counterService;
}

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String myPostMethod(Object obj) {
    counterService.increment("mycontroller.post.method");
    //...
    return "myPostMethod";
}

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String myGetMethod() {
    counterService.increment("mycontroller.get.method");
    //...
    return "myGetMethod";
}
```